# What does $F$ stand for in this equation $\Delta f = \Delta_0 f + n \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 r}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, spheres, laplacian

I am reading *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis* by Jost, and this is one of the exercises concering Laplace operators:

3.1.a)

The Laplace operator $\Delta$ on $S^n$ on functions $f: S^n \to \mathbb{R}$ can be obtained from the Euclidean Laplace operator $\Delta_0$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ via

$$\Delta f = \Delta_0 f + n \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial^2 r}.$$

That is all there is in the exercise, besides a note on polar coodrinates on the sphere $S^n$.

Any idea what $F$ refers to in this equation? I guess it should be some extension of the function $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, but I guess it could not be $F= f( \frac{x}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert})$, because this would not have a radial derivative.

Comment: I assume the misplaced superscript on $\partial^2 F/\partial r^2$ is yours and not the book's. I would assume that $F$ is a function on $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and $f=F|_{S^n}$ and that we interpret the right-hand side as the restriction to $S^n$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, but what should this function $F$ then be? Or do you mean any smooth $F$ that has $f = F\vert_{S^n}$ fulfills this property? This seems inplausible since I could choose how fast $F$ changes w.r.t. $r$ then freely.